# SE site for Microsoft Office questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There is so much low-grade help online with Microsoft Office that it is difficult to find good answers.  I have a question about numbering headers, and would like to post to some Stack Exchange site but am not sure if there is an appropriate one.

Such a site would be for the zillions of us who use Office every day, and want to use it well.

Comment: this should be migrated to meta.superuser.com ... ;)

Comment: No, don't migrate this; you have to know about SU to know about MSU, and once you know about SU there's no need for this question. (I know you were joking, @cularis, but I wanted to be clear for future readers.)

Comment: @Popular Demand: The OP knows about SuperUser, [he even has 150 rep there](http://superuser.com/users/75071/daniel-williams).

Comment: SO right now has 7.5k Outlook questions, SU has 3k. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook vs http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook . I wonder why there are so many SE sites, even for RPG, but not for Office.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [Office Suite proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33681/office-suite) on Area 51 has been closed as duplicate of [Super User](https://superuser.com), and it is now deleted.

[image: screenshot]

Questions about Microsoft Office should be asked on *Super User*.
Use [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office) as tag for generic questions about Microsoft Office, or one of the version tags for questions about a specific Microsoft Office version (e.g. [microsoft-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2007)).